# BabelJS browser plugin issues while trying to use yield and next

Tags: javascript, generator

I am trying to use BabelJS in order to have yield capabilities in older browsers. I am using the following code:

```
var m_foo = null; 

function hi(){
    m_foo = function* Run() {
    console.log("section #1")
    yield true;
    console.log("section #2")
    yield true;
    console.log("section #3");
    yield false;
}

function bye(){
  try
  {
    var result = true;
    while (result)
    {
      result = m_foo.next();
    }
    alert("good");
  }
  catch(ex)
  {
    alert(ex.message);
  }
}

hi();
bye();
```

but I keep getting an exception 
`m_foo.next() is not a function`

[Here is my code in Babel'JS online converter](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=true&code=var%20m_foo%20%3D%20null%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20hi()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Am_foo%20%3D%20function*()%20%7B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22section%20%231%22)%0D%0Ayield%20true%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22section%20%232%22)%3B%0D%0Ayield%20false%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bye()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20try%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20result%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20while%20(result)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20m_foo.next()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%22good%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20catch(ex)%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(ex.message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ahi()%3B%0D%0Abye()%3B)

Can anyone please direct me on what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: `m_foo` is a generator function. It returns an iterator when it is called. The iterator has a next method. But you never call `m_foo` and it doesn't have a `next` method itself (as the error tells you). Also `next` doesn't return what you seem to think it does. Wherever you read about generators, it seems to be wrong.  I suggest to read the MDN documentation first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: so i will need to do something like "var test = m_foo()" and then "test.next()" ? what will it return? because when I used yield without babelJS i was able to use it in this way

Comment: *"because when I used yield without babelJS"* In which environemnt? See the following link for what `next()` returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterator .